# Dynamtic In Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using a checkbox list to selected orders for export and I am using the following to export the orders My Question is how do i place the chracher , within the in statement using the below code ?

```
  For Each obj As Object In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        tempstring = Chr(39) & obj.ToString() & Chr(39)
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", tempstring)
    Next
```

Function to return sql

```
   Friend Function GetDistinctOrdersForLocations(OrderNumber As String) As String Implements  
    iScriptBuilder.GetDistinctOrdersForLocations
    Dim retVal As String = "SELECT DISTINCT location, ordernumber FROM orders "
    retVal &= "where orders.ordernumber in (" & OrderNumber & ")"
    Return retVal
   End Function
```

This is producing this sql through the above function

```
SELECT DISTINCT location, ordernumber FROM orders where orders.ordernumber
 in ('Puals Test V1' 
 'Puals Test V2'   

)
```

Comment: Be carefull with this approach, if one of your strings contains a ' you'll be in trouble.

Comment: @the_lotus it wont theirs filtering on the product number

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does. You create `tempstring` by quoting `object.ToString()` in single quotes. Then you add it to the `StringBuilder` **without any change**, because the `String.Join` doesn't do anything for just one string. `String.Join` joins a **list of strings** together using the separator, but you're not passing in a list, but just a single string - there's nothing to join here.

What you need to do is

```
For Each obj As Object In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
    tempstring = Chr(39) & obj.ToString() & Chr(39)
    If sb.Length > 0 THEN
       sb.Append(",")
    End If
    sb.Append(tempstring)
Next
```

This appends a comma to the `StringBuilder` in case there's some content already and then it appends the new string.

Answer (score 0):

Using built in functionality:

```
retVal &= string.Join(
    ",", 
    CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        .Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x.ToString())));
```

Also watch out for SQL injection when doing such a construct. It might be safer to move this to a stored procedure or to pass a variable number of prepared statements.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/540352) for a safer way of achieving your goal.